# can some one guide me how to use move it for path planning in case of manipulators?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am looking forward or the path planning of manipulators to avoid obstacles using potential field method. i am new to ros . so i hope the community will  help me to complete my work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219654/can-some-one-guide-me-how-to-use-move-it-for-path-planning-in-case-of-manipulators?/) by [alexi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24636/alexi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-10-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!,

If you are searching some tutorials to use moveit! you should check the tutorials from the official [moveit!](http://moveit.ros.org/documentation/tutorials/) website.

If what you are trying to do is some research about how the path planning works in moveit!. You should know that moveit! uses [ompl](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/) as the default path planner library. So you should search for some documentation about this software.

Anyway if you are new to ROS and want to learn to use it what you should do first is to do the basic tutorials from the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), to start learning about the basic concepts, the key to understand the ROS system.

I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [donmrsir](https://answers.ros.org/users/19553/donmrsir/) with karma: 363 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2